# Java,Lang.OutOfMemoryError on Xamarin android deployment

Tags: java, c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

Hello I am currently having this message whenever I try to deploy my app to the emulator and it happened exactly where I attach a layout to an activity i-e

```
SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
```

The complete error message says " Failed to allocate a 6569942 byte allocation with 1048576 free bytes and 95 until OOM.

here is my layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http//schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/coordLayout"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_marginTop="40sp"
                android:id="@+id/logo"
                android:layout_width="200sp"
                android:layout_height="200sp"
                android:src="@drawable/cpdep"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/user"
                android:layout_marginTop="20sp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_width="300sp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Username" />
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/pass"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_width="300sp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Password"
                android:layout_marginTop="20sp" />
            <Button
                android:layout_marginTop="20sp"
                android:layout_marginRight="40sp"
                android:id="@+id/myButton"
                android:layout_width="100sp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Log in"
                android:layout_gravity="right" />
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Do you have any idea on how to solve this? thanks in advance for your help

Comment: How your layout looks like? Could you update your original post showing this?

Comment: yes of course if this can help

Comment: You want to try updating all you "sp" to "dp" except for the textSize (if any)? That being said you will had the ImageView with width of 200dp and height of 200dp.

Comment: If you open in the explorer the file "cpdep" what is the size in MBs and full width and height?

Comment: thanks for noticing me for the height and width that was supposed tobe in dp and not in sp. but it didn't solve the error and  cpdep is exactly 2.89 MB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figure out what went wrong , it was because of the size of the image I use in my layout. it was 2.89 MB with a resolution of 6200x6199. I resize it with photoshop and everything is working properly thanks to @apenide